Import CSV with datetime column
I am trying to import a CSV in PostgreSQL which has one column with datetime2(7) type.
Getting error as below

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "CREATE_S"
CONTEXT:  COPY table_s, line 1, column CREATE_S: "CREATE_S"

What should be done to pass the datetime field.
So far, I tried to make the datetime field as character varying and imported successfully.
But, now I am unable to alter the column back to timestamp. Error

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "CREATE_S"
SQL state: 22007

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Looks like you try to insert the header as content, did you set HEADER TRUE in your copy statement?

@dale k Big thanks . I am able to import now

PostgreSQL has no datetime2 type.

@schwen Yes. I am aware of that. I am creating equivalent type in postgres

Apparerntly I countered another problem in a table ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "57:28.7" 2. CONTEXT: COPY table_h, line 2, column fcreate_s: "57:28.7". @frank Any suggestion

Well, that's not a timestamp (date is missing and it's over 24 hours), that looks like an INTERVAL. Change your data type, or clean your data before you try to import .
